# Make Text-boxes/Button stay in position for different resolutions?

Tags: html, asp.net, css

I have a DIV that has a background as a box that i created. Now i have set this DIV to scale for different resolutions like this:

```
#Information {
    margin-left:37%;
    display:block;
    background-image:url(../Images/LoginBox_v2.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    height:60%;
    width:60%;
    background-size:contain;
    min-width: 400px;
    min-height: 400px;
    max-height: 946px;
    max-width: 946px;
}
```

Then inside that div i have 2 more DIV tags; One containing the Username and Password Text-boxes and the other a button, Like this:

```
#UserPass {
    margin-top: 10%;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -1%;
}

#Button{
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 20%;
    margin-left: 10%;
}
```

This is the Username and Password Textbox CSS if you needed to see it  :

```
#tb_Username {
    width: 100%; 
    min-width: 165px;
    max-width: 850px;
}

#tb_Password {
    width: 100%; 
    min-width: 165px;
    max-width: 485px;
    margin-top: 5%;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="Information">
        <div id="UserPass">
                <asp:TextBox runat="server"  CssClass="inputs" placeholder="Username..." id="tb_Username" Width="485px"/>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" TextMode="Password" CssClass="inputs" placeholder="Password..." id="tb_Password" Width="485px"/>
        </div>

     <div id="Button">
        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" CssClass="s3d twitter" id="buttonlogin" Text="Login" OnClick="buttonlogin_Click"/>
     </div>
     </div>
```

**Problem** is that when i test and shrink the web browser the textboxs and buttons wont stay inside the box DIV tag (Information) and this is what happens:

[image]

**How can i get the User and Pass Textbox to go smaller and stay in the box as well as doing the same with the button**

Comment: Research media queries

Comment: @mituw16 I will have alook into it if you have anymore information would love to know :)

Comment: The text boxes and buttons won't stay inside the box DIV due to the use of absolute positioning.

Comment: @JohanVdR How can i get around this? But still by using absolute positioning?